# `CGEventPost` creates different event characters on key up

Tags: macos, keyboard, core-graphics

I simulate a key press on macOS 12 using `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString` and `CGEventPost`. Despite creating the key up and down events with the same parameters, the resulting `NSEvent` for key up has a different character value. Why?

Here is how I generate the key press:

```
    CGEventRef keyDown, keyUp;
    UniChar unicode = 'P';

    keyDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 0, true);
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyDown, 1, &unicode);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, keyDown);
    CFRelease(keyDown);

    keyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 0, false);
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(keyUp, 1, &unicode);
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, keyUp);
    CFRelease(keyUp);
```

In my first responder, I have:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s", [event.characters UTF8String]);
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s", [event.characters UTF8String]);
}
```

But this prints

> 2022-09-08 12:04:55.570063-0400 test[14010:5447113] P

> 2022-09-08 12:04:55.570252-0400 test[14010:5447113] a

Why does the key up event have the character value "a" instead of "P", despite being create with the same parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since I totally misunderstood your question, I rewrote the answer.

**Why it shows lowercase 'a'?**

Take a look at this line:

```
keyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 0, false);
```

The second parameter, it's a virtual key code. You pass a zero to it.
which is `kVK_ANSI_A`(0x00) in events.h.

It's exactly the lowercase "a."

You can do an experiment by replacing 2
key codes in `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` with 1. you will find it works the same, except it prints "s" in `keyup:` method. As 0x01 is `kVK_ANSI_S`, which is the keycode for letter "s".

**As for why it does not print "P" in `keyup:`?**

Take a look at [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706245?answerId=714368022#714368022) form eskimo:

> CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString has always been problematic. It seems that something changed in macOS 12 to make this happen more often, but this has always been a possibility.

If you look at the documentation of [CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456028-cgeventkeyboardsetunicodestring)

You will notice this statement:

> Note that application frameworks may ignore the Unicode string in a keyboard event and do their own translation based on the virtual keycode and perceived event state.

So I think your unicode string is ignored in `keyup:` method.

Is it acceptable to you?

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "You are using those APIs in the wrong way" - I disagree, this is a simple example but I *want* to set the unicode character(s) associated with the event. The application I'm injecting input to uses the unicode value from the key events.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Maybe you can describe your senario more clear so I can understand your code better and help.

Comment: I'm injecting key input into my own application to simulate typing. While using key codes works well as least for ASCII; it becomes challenging and fragile to translate non-ASCII characters into keystroke combinations (particularly taking into account that the keyboard layout may not be en-US). `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString` works really well; but in certain cases I see weird results in my application. I wonder if this is related to the behaviour I notice in my question: the key up event not matching the key down; and I'd like to understand the reason for that.

Comment: Rewrote the answer bro. Take a look

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite right I think. I understand that the key code is set in `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`, but it doesn't explain why the unicode string that I overrode is not the same in the key up event. Since both events are created the same way :) Also - I control the application that is receiving the event, so it's not the case that I'm ignoring the `characters` properly of the event. I am concerned that this API might be buggy on macOS 12 and I suppose I need to test on a prior macOS version...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible you are using the wrong event type.

```
kCGEventKeyDown
```

and

```
kCGEventKeyUp
```

are not the same as

```
kCGEventKeyPress

kCGEventKeyPress
```

is the event that is sent when a key is pressed and released.

```
kCGEventKeyDown
```

is sent when a key is pressed.

```
kCGEventKeyUp
```

is sent when a key is released.

I probably didn't understand all of your code so sorry if my answer isn't helpful

Comment: I don't think so, because whether it's a key up or down event is controlled by the third parameter to `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`. But thank you for your answer!